# Substantiv für Teilnehmer eines Tutoriums/Tutorats?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request, noun

Existiert ein Substantiv für einen Teilnehmer eines Tutoriums/Tutorats einer Universität?

Comment: Bei uns hieß das Tutorium *Übung*, und die Teilnehmer einer Übung *Übling*, aber das war vermutlich eine lokale Bezeichnung.

Comment: @dirkt Bei uns war ein "Tutorium" eine Veranstaltung mit ca. 20 Studenten, in der man dem Tutor auch Fragen stellen konnte; eine "Übung" war hingegen eine Veranstaltung mit ca. 300 Studenten...

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Ich weiß, Vortragsübungen gibt es auch (die sind ein Gräuel, gab es bei uns zum Glück nicht). Bei uns war eine Übung eine Veranstaltung mit ca. 20 Studenten, bei der die Studenten Präsenzaufgaben in Kleingruppen lösen, während der Gruppenleiter (Hiwi oder Assistent) herumgeht und Denkanstöße gibt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Für mich waren das immer meine [Tutanden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tutand) und der Duden kennt das auch. Die weibliche Form ist [Tutandin](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tutandin).

Answer (score 4):

Alldieweil die von Carsten S. vorgeschlagenen *Tutanden* sicherlich formal richtig sind, sind sie doch als Wort wenig verbreitet (bis hin zur Unverständlichkeit in dem Lateinischen fernerstehenden Kreisen).

Wie wär's, aus solchen praktischen Gründen heraus, ganz simpel mit

> Studenten im Tutorium

Comment: +1 für Umgangssprache!